# How to set token auth in nginx for image?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, token

I have an `upload` folder which contains many sub folders, in which contains many images. eg.

```
upload/
    subfolder1/
        2015/
            02/
            03/
    subfolder2/
        2015/
        2016/
            01/
    subfolder2/
```

I want to just for images under `subfolder1` and `subfolder2` to set token auth on Nginx level. Seems this one may meet the need: https://github.com/abedra/nginx-auth-token-module

The need is, I want our inner project to have access to our images by token, for public, I want those images forbidden to have access to. I'm using LNMP, I don't want to do this on PHP level. But I'm not familiar with Nginx. The auth mechanism I want may like this:

```
$etime = time() + 600; 
$key = 'token';   // token 
$path = '/dir/pic.jpg'; //
$sign = substr(md5($key.'&'.$etime.'&'.$path), 12,8).$etime;
```

And I want it to be passed on URL, how to do?

Comment: That module doesn't look like it's got a very big following. There's only 1 contributor and no documentation on the web. You could try contacting the author for support, or bite the bullet and use PHP. I could write up a simple token authentication engine for you..

Comment: @cantelope wow, could you?

Comment: Yeah, but it would involve a database and PHP. Do you have PHP enabled? MySQL?

Comment: @cantelope It seems complicated, I just want a token mechanism, should I use PHP method anyway?

Comment: I would use PHP. It's a pretty simple job for a PHP script. Can I ask why you're using Nginx instead of something like Apache? Apache has an auth token module and tons of documentation.

Comment: @cantelope Because we use Nginx on production, and web server seem a more safety way because even PHP is down, we can still read the images. But if we do it on PHP level, when PHP is down, images cannot shown, and  maybe PHP is not a better way to output static image?